# How to get the last year in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I need to get the last year (Year -1) in Xaml.

I've the following code:

```
 <Label 
     Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{}{0:yyyy}'}"/>
```

Comment: But you are binding. Anyhow, I think you're looking for a converter.

Comment: "Without binding"? Do you want to set the label text property in code behind?

Comment: @StephenQuan Thx for your tip. I solved with a converter.